Jdbc.sink.error An unexpected error occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkConfig
Confluent platform add sink connector image
Trying add sink connector in confluent platform it give me errors
The connector install manually -- confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.7.6
{
"class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"type": "sink",
"version": "10.7.6"
},
{
"class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"type": "source",
"version": "10.7.6"
}

source connector working properly , confluent UI did not give any error.
I am using locally Confluent 10.7.4.--confluent version v3.2.1
Java version--
openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.22+7-adhoc.admin.jdk11u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.22+7-adhoc.admin.jdk11u, mixed mode)
Error in Connect log
ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connector plugins/io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector/config/validate (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:64)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:123)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource.validateConfigs(ConnectorPluginsResource.java:109)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:554)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:181)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector.config(JdbcSinkConnector.java:70)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:580)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$6(AbstractHerder.java:470)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
... 1 more

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value insert for configuration insert.mode: Invalid enumerator
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkConfig$EnumValidator.ensureValid(JdbcSinkConfig.java:658)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1270)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:159)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:179)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:218)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkConfig.<clinit>(JdbcSinkConfig.java:362)
... 8 more

What is the problem ?

Can you go back further in the log and see if you can find an ExceptionInInitializerError? If you can, that should give you the real cause of the error. A NoClassDefFoundError with the message Could not initialize class .... means that the JVM has already tried and failed to perform static initialization on that class, so it doesn't bother trying it again.

Thank you for comment @LukeWoodward ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connector-plugins/io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector/config/validate (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:64) java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError I Think this is same error when i try the add connector in confluent Control center.  Also  i try with  Command ( -X POST )  error: {"servlet":"org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-7d5f8007", "message":"Request failed.","url":"/connectors","status":"500"}

Please edit your question and include the full stacktrace of the exception with the ExceptionInInitializerError. You haven't posted the full stacktrace in your comment, but it seems that what you have posted ends before where the useful info is.

Thanks @LukeWoodward. I edited and  added the full logs of ExceptionInInitializerError .

Thanks. I took an initial look at the root-cause exception (the one right at the bottom) but couldn't seen an obvious way that it could be triggered. I'll keep looking into it.

I've had another look at this and cannot reproduce the problem. However, I have just recalled an issue which affected a similar question. Are you by any chance using a Turkish locale?

Thanks a lot @LukeWoodward . I solve with Change the my system Language.

This is a bug in the Confluent JDBC Connector. It fails to initialise itself if it is being run in the Turkish locale.
The bug is in this method:
    public static <E> EnumValidator in(E[] enumerators) {
      final List<String> canonicalValues = new ArrayList<>(enumerators.length);
      final Set<String> validValues = new HashSet<>(enumerators.length * 2);
      for (E e : enumerators) {
        canonicalValues.add(e.toString().toLowerCase());
        validValues.add(e.toString().toUpperCase());
        validValues.add(e.toString().toLowerCase());
      }
      return new EnumValidator(canonicalValues, validValues);
    }

The problem is that the calls to .toLowerCase() and .toUpperCase() do not specify the locale in which they are performing case conversion. So the conversion happens in the default locale. For the insert.mode configuration default, the valid values are those that are the names of the InsertMode enum (INSERT, UPSERT and UPDATE), plus the lower-case values of these. In the Turkish locale, these are ınsert, upsert and update.
The JdbcSinkConfig class contains some functionality to check that all default values for configuration are valid. The insert.mode parameter is one of the configuration parameters whose value is checked. The default value for insert.mode is insert. Of course, in the Turkish locale, this isn't one of the valid values, hence an exception is thrown.
If it is an option for you to use an English locale instead of a Turkish locale, then I would expect things to work. If not, you are waiting on Confluent to fix this bug. I've reported this bug on their GitHub repo here.

Thanks for your effort @LukeWoodward. You can solve it by Changing Local Language.
